# function_exists returns false every time

Tags: php, oop, function

I'm trying to check whether a function exists or not but I keep getting false in my if

I try to call the function like this, where **$function is the function name**:

```
if (function_exists($this->module->$function))
{
    $this->module->$function($vars);
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

The variable `module` is defined as the class where the function should be called:

```
$this->module = $module;
$this->module = new $this -> module;
```

Am I missing something here?
Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just could figure it out:
Using [method_exists()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) solved my problem

```
method_exists($this->module,$function)
```

I answered this question on my own for people who may have the same problem!

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [`method_exists()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php):

```
if (method_exists($this->module, $function)) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to check whether method exists and not the function:

```
if (method_exists($this->module, $function))
{
    $this->module->$function($vars);
}
else
{
    echo 'no';
}
```

Have a look at the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php

Answer (score 2):

`function_exists` takes the name of a function as a string, and has no concept of class hierarchy.

If `$function` is the name of the function, simply use this code:

```
if(function_exists($function)) {
    // Call $function().
}
```

However, looking at your code it looks more like you want to detect if a method of an object exists.

`method_exists` takes two parameters, 1: the object to test on, 2: the name of the method to detect.

```
if(method_exists($this->module, $function)) {
    $this->module->$function($vars);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

function_exists() expects a String as parameter. This will do the trick:

```
method_exists($this->module, $function);
```

Good luck!